# nodejs on close handler not firing behind a relay

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, server-sent-events

I have a node/express app with a streaming end point that deals with SSE, i would like to fire the req.on('close') handler when the user closes the browser or the tab. So i added the handler inside the /stream route and it is working fine.

But if my streaming end point is served behind a web server relay then the req.on('close') handler is not firing when the browser/tab is closed.

i.e. when i close the browser/tab of the original end point /api/stream then it fires the on close handler with no issues but if this end point is behind a web server relay something like this /api/livestream which would internally call the original end point /api/stream and now when i close the browser where /api/livestream runs it is not firing the req.on('close') event handler.

Is there anything that could be done to fire the close handler even when the end point is served behind a relay.

Comment: I guess it would only depend on the relay, if it closes or not the stream when the tab is closed. So unless you have access to that particular relay, I do not think there's a way

Comment: @nicovank it is a simple web server relay, so wondering is there anything that could be done at the relay level to make the close event fire.